# Creating a new Linux Command without touching the bashrc

Tags: bash

I want to write a shell script that allows me to do this in the bash terminal :
`Mycommand [options] [param]` .
Is there any way that my shell would recognize Mycommand **without having to modify the .bashrc** ? ( the goal here is to be able to give the script file to someone and they wouldn't have to add anything to their path and still be able to use it as said )

Comment: Put that script somewhere within your PATH and make it executable.

Comment: but that's exactly what i want to avoid, i want to simply give the script file to someone and they would be able to use it as said in the question, without having to add it to their path

Comment: There is no way around it having to be in the `PATH`. There are a few directories where you typically throws user-specific scripts: `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` are examples.

Comment: A non-solution is adding the current directory to the path: while it would enable what you want to do, it opens up serious security issues (and you'd have to modify `PATH` anyway).

Comment: You might want to consider how tools like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) are installed. You tell users to `bash -c "$(curl https://some.url.example.com)"` and the downloaded script takes care of the rest.

Comment: Give the user the script.  If they want to execute it, they can give the full path to wherever they put it.  If they don't want to give a full path, they can put it in a directory that's already in their PATH.  Configuring their environment is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

They can run the script by running it from the directory where it is saved:

```
cd dir/with/script
./script.sh
```

Or

```
~/bin/script.sh
```

If the script is saved in the bin directory in the home of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Define a shell alias. For example, the following alias is called `x` and it executes `ls -alF *.py`:

```sh
$ alias x="ls -alF *.py"
```

No files need to be written in order for a shell alias to be defined or used.

Now you can type `x` into a shell prompt in the shell where you defined the alias, and it will return a detailed list of your Python source files.

```sh
$ alias x="ls -alF *.py"
$ x
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mslinn mslinn  653 Feb 19 17:19 django-admin.py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mslinn mslinn 1675 Sep 19  2020 jp.py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mslinn mslinn  594 Sep 19  2020 rst2html.py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mslinn mslinn 6413 Sep 19  2020 wsdump.py*
```

If you want to be able to specify the pattern for the files to list, do not include that in the alias. For example:

```sh
$ alias y="ls -alF"
$ y *.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mslinn mslinn 606 Nov 17 20:31 README.md
```

You can even just define default parameters, and add more:

```sh
$ alias z="ls -a"
$ z -lF *.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mslinn mslinn 606 Nov 17 20:31 README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script can call a script within the same folder, to add an alias to the bash session and create variables for your script to run, this would be available for the duration of the bash session. Once you have ended this bash session, the alias and the variables, the script created would be lost.